# Filtering out ROS2 rclcpp and rcl debug logs

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using ROS2 Foxy. My node has several types logging statements (info, debug, error). When I set the logging level to info, i see my error and info statements, which is expected. when i set the logging level to debug, i see all my logging statements but i also see bunch of logging statements from RCL and RCLCPP which I don't want to see. Is there a way I an filter out these system logs and only see my custom logging statements?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389629/filtering-out-ros2-rclcpp-and-rcl-debug-logs/) by [apoorvcn47](https://answers.ros.org/users/10626/apoorvcn47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahopsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/75387/ahopsu/) on 2022-02-10**:
I have the exact same need already for a long time, and haven't really found any proper solution. The trick I'm using now is for example
`ros2 run package node --ros-args --log-level DEBUG | grep -v '[rcl]'`
which removes the rcl stuff from the terminal output, but it will still write all the stuff in the log file. I would like to have a solution, where even into the file is not written the rcl stuff, because my log files become very heavy to handle, and could be reduced by 80% of it size just by removing all the rcl stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set log level specifically for the underlying components of your node (rcl, rclcpp, dds).

```
ros2 run package node --ros-args --log-level DEBUG --log-level rcl:=INFO
```

This way your node will output on DEBUG level, but rcl will be muted.

---

Originally posted by [tommy_erko](https://answers.ros.org/users/124890/tommy_erko/) with karma: 26 on 2022-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1